# How often should each object's GetObjectData method be called during custom serialization?

Tags: .net, performance, serialization, iserializable

I'm serializing the data in my app using custom serialization i.e. each of the classes I'm storing has the `[Serializable]` attribute and implements `ISerializable`. The object graph being serialized is reasonably complex with lots of cross-references between the objects/classes. The serialization *works*, but it's pretty slow. :(

By putting a breakpoint in each relevant class's `GetObjectData` method, I've found that I'm getting many, many more hits than I've got objects.

I'm confused - my understanding of the serialization framework was that it would store each object only once, even if the object graph contained multiple references to it. I assumed that this meant each object's `GetObjectData` method would need to be called only once during saving. Am I wrong?

And if so, is there anything I can do in this approach to reduce the number of calls to my classes' `GetObjectData` methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata.aspx) do not guarantee just 1 call per object instance.

Have you tried this with different formatters?  There are comments [here](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/net-remoting-runtime-serialization/bug-getobjectdata-called-multiple-times-for-single-reference-51177.shtml) to the effect that selected work was being done to improve this. specifically for Indigo (aka WCF).

> It is not guaranteed that this method
>   will be called only once per object
>   instance during serialization.
>   Therefore, the method should be
>   implemented in such a way that its
>   behavior will be the same regardless
>   of the number of times it is called.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't spotted that.

Comment: Turns out, in the end, that I hadn't spotted something pretty fundamental in my object graph. One of the properties I was serializing returned a collection of objects created anew, on-the-fly every time the property was accessed. Not only that, but each object held references to other parts of the graph. Frankly, it's a miracle the serialization ever finished. Ooops.

Comment: @Mal - glad you got this sorted out